# facebook like count not showing up on a specific domain with html5 or iframe code, in all browsers

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-opengraph, xfbml

I appreciate this could be construed as a somewhat lame question but the issue has me utterly perplexed. I simply cannot get the like button count to show up for a particular domain. The exact same code on an alternative domain works fine.

The problematic domain is www.gold.org. I have made four test cases, each using code basically verbatim from the FB website. In each example the url to be liked points to the domain's homepage (unless specified).

http://www.gold.org/test.php - HTML 5 implementation, this page also contains links to the other examples and open graph info.

I have taken time to ensure that the correct OG tags are in place (using the facebook debug tool), that each site has admin ids and have even gone as far as to implement facebook/insights for each site. The gold.org domain has used addthis.com analytics for sometime and I have recently upgraded the code to use native social button code. Insights reports show enough traffic to warrant the count being displayed, and an fql query for the gold.org homepage currently reports a count of 86.

Below is some sample code from the gold.org domain, for those unable/unwilling to check the examples above. The test case in the goldinspirations.com domain is the same, but with relevant urls and OG tags for that site.

If anyone could shed light on this I would be entirely grateful. I have read many other questions/answers related to this issue here on the FB stackoverflow site, and I believe I have implemented everything correctly. Feel free to shoot me down in flames if I have missed somethingm, I promise to slap my forehead and say DOH.

Many thanks

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>FB Test</title>
<meta name="robots" content="index,follow" /> 
<meta name="copyright" content="Copyright (c) 2012 World Gold Council" /> 
<meta name="author" content="http://www.gold.org" /> 
<meta name="publisher" content="World Gold Council" /> 


<meta property="og:title" content="Homepage &gt; World Gold Council"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="The World Gold Council – the market development organisation of the gold industry and voice of authority for gold" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.gold.org/"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.gold.org/assets/static/www.gold.org/img/favicon-apple.png"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="World Gold Council"/>
<meta property="fb:admins" content="100001681197681,536819656" />

</head>

<body>
<script>
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.gold.org" data-send="true" data-layout="button_count" data-width="300" data-show-faces="false" data-font="arial"></div>                    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The like button seems to be working.  I have "liked" it with 3 different accounts; The counter is incremented and the "like" story **is** published.  This could be a transient issue.

Comment: Sorry... not sure if I'm being thick here... do you mean to say that when you first arrive at the page you see a like count, prior to liking it? I agree that liking it increments the count to one, but refresh and the count disappears. It shoudl be between 80-90 at present.

I'd like it to be transient, however the issue first reared its head on a dev server before xmas, and then remained once I got the code onto the live infrastructure a couple of days ago.

Many thanks.

Comment: With a user that has not yet liked the URL, I can now see three likes... I do believe that they are all mine...

Comment: ok... I saw your 3 likes earlier today... seems things have changed slightly now! see below. tx for your help Lix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.gold.org/test.php > 702 likes
http://www.gold.org/test2.php > 702 likes
http://www.gold.org/test3.php > 3.1m likes
http://www.goldinspirations.com/test.php > 92 likes

http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://www.gold.org > 702 likes
http://graph.facebook.com/http://gold.org > 702 likes

This does concern me: http://graph.facebook.com/10150203036463274 doesn't display much information on your likes or shares like others tend to list like: http://graph.facebook.com/cocacola

Comment: Hi DCMS. thanks, I agree and see the same stats now. This is all a bit odd. I think the problem, as Lix said earlier, is that it may have been transient. was catching up with itself or something, who knows.

What I will say is that its a PIA having to back engineer all this FB stuff.

Re the FB graph output gold.org vs cocacola. My hunch is this could be because gold.org has no real involvement with FB other than the like button. I'd imagine coca cola has done slightly more! I'd be interested in your input. +1 for pointing it out however (my reputation doesn't allow me to vote at present).

Comment: Probably some data migration, data latency, or improper cache clearing/updating happened.

Comment: Neither of those listed above show the count, I am also having the same problem on my site. I am using Chrome.

Comment: Sure they do. http://graph.facebook.com/http://gold.org is showing 806 likes.  And http://graph.facebook.com/cocacola is showing 42 million.